# Null pointer access error in SystemVerilog

Tags: simulation, system-verilog, testbench

I am practising the SystemVerilog class concepts. I got an error while running the code:

```
Fatal Error: RUNTIME_0029 code.sv (67): Null pointer access.
```

Here is the code:

```
typedef enum bit[1:0]{SMALL=2'b 00, MEDIUM=2'b 01, LARGE=2'b 11} pkt_type;

class eth_pkt;
  //CLASS PROPERTIES
  protected bit[55:0] preamble;
  protected rand bit[47:0] sa; 
  protected rand bit[7:0] len;
  protected rand byte data[$];
  protected static int count;
  rand pkt_type ptype;
  
  //CLASS CONSTRAINTS
  
  constraint data_l{ 
    data.size()==len;//data queue gets populated
    foreach(data[i]) 
      data[i] inside{8'h 1F, 8'h 5F};
        
  }
  constraint sa_value{ 
    sa inside{[100:150]};
        
  }
  constraint pkt_category{
    len inside{[1:10]};
    (ptype==SMALL)->(len inside{[1:3]});
    (ptype==MEDIUM)->(len inside{[4:6]});
    (ptype==LARGE)->(len inside{[7:10]});
  }
  
  //CLASS METHODS
  
  function new();
    preamble={28{2'b10}};
    count++;
  endfunction
  
  function void print( string name="eth_pkt");
    $display("ptype=%s",ptype);
    $display("printing the fields of %s",name);
    $display("preamble=%0h",preamble);
    $display("sa=%0h",sa);
    $display("len=%0h",len);
    foreach(data[i])
      $display("data[%0d]=%0h",i,data[i]);
    $display("count=%h",count);
  endfunction
  
  function void copy( output eth_pkt cpkt);
    cpkt=new();
    cpkt.preamble=preamble;cpkt.sa=sa;cpkt.len=len; cpkt.data=data;cpkt.count=count; cpkt.ptype=ptype;
  endfunction
  
  function bit compare(eth_pkt cmp_pkt);
    if(cmp_pkt.preamble==preamble && cmp_pkt.sa==sa && cmp_pkt.len==len && cmp_pkt.data==data && cmp_pkt.count==count && cmp_pkt.ptype==ptype)
      begin $display("pkts matched"); return 1;end
    else 
      begin $display("pkts don't matched"); return 0;end
  endfunction
  
  function void pack(output byte qout[$]);
    qout={>> byte{preamble,sa,len,data,count}};
    // pkt_type can't be packed as it's size isn't a multiple of byte
  endfunction
  
  function void unpack(input byte qin[$]);
    preamble={qin[0],qin[1],qin[2],qin[3],qin[4],qin[5],qin[6]};
    sa={qin[7],qin[8],qin[9],qin[10],qin[11],qin[12]};
    len={qin[13]};
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
      data[i]=qin[14+i];
    //qin doesn't have pkt_type information as it couldn't be packed. we can get pkt_type with the help of length info which qin have
    if(len inside{[1:20]}) ptype=SMALL; 
    if(len inside{[21:100]}) ptype=MEDIUM;
    if(len inside{[101:255]}) ptype=LARGE; 
  endfunction
  
endclass

  module tt();
  eth_pkt p1,p2,p3,p4;
  byte bitQ[$];
  initial begin
  p1=new();
  assert(p1.randomize);
  p1.print("p1");
  p1.copy(p2);
    assert(p2.compare(p1));
  p2.print("p2");
  p3=new();
  assert(p3.randomize);
  p3.print("p3");
  p3.pack(bitQ);
  p4.unpack(bitQ);
  p3.print("p3");
   assert( p2.compare(p1));
  end
endmodule
```

Here is the code link https://www.edaplayground.com/x/9ZuG                                   Someone please tell what mistake have I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `tt` module.

You declared a handle to the `p4` object here, as expected:

```
  eth_pkt p1,p2,p3,p4;
```

However, you tried to access the handle before you allocated memory to it:

```
  p4.unpack(bitQ);
```

You need to construct the object using the `new` method:

```
  p4 = new();
  p4.unpack(bitQ);
```

This fixes the error.

Comment: Yes I found my mistake just now and came here to answer it myself but you had already answered it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Kartikey: A lot of times you find the answer right after you ask the question.

Answer (score -1):

A null pointer usually means the pointer is set to zero. Pointers are used to point to a memory location.

In most cases, it is assumed the programmer did not want to access the very 1st byte of computer memory (usually reserved for the computer's boot up activity). So, when a program encounters a null pointer, it usually throws an error. Likely, you need to set the pointer to the appropriate location in memory.